# Mobile menu not working in responsive layout

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

You guys helped me out BIG TIME yesterday with resolving my responsive slider issue, and that was AWESOME!

Once that started working something else stopped working for some reason. When reducing the window size to shift the main menue bar into the condensed mobile menu, it does not work when tapped or clicked. The menu used to roll down when active, but now, nothing.

Going a little crazy over here trying to figure out the issue, and was hoping I can get some more eyes on it.

Once again, thanks so much in advance!!

here is the URL: http://4grain.bmdigitalgroup.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting this error in the console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.$el.on(this.on,function(e){if($(this).prop("tagName")==="A"){e.preventDefault()}e.stopPropagation();scope.trigger(scope.triggered)})')
```

I would check the tagName property.

Comment: Hmm. interesting.. I will check it out! Thanks, Jordan!